# Scala - Supertype of a type parameter

Tags: scala, types, type-systems

In Scala, how can I do something like this:

```
def cast [Type] (x: _ >: Type, errMsg: String): Type = {
    if (x.isInstanceOf[Type]) {
        x.asInstanceOf[Type]
    } else {
        throw new Exception(errMsg) 
    }
}
```

`x: _ >: Type` (a notation that does not exist in Scala) meaning "the type of x is any supertype of Type".

Comment: What's your intent ? What's the difference with just calling `x.asInstanceOf[Type]` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If x can be of any superType of `Type`, then certainly it can be `Any`. This is no constraint at all, you can just write `x : Any`

On another line, due to type erasure, you `x.isInstanceOf[Type]` will do no useful check. You cannot check on a type parameter. (You have to ensure that the type information will be available at runtime. You can get to something with `Manifest`).

Comment: Interesting. Is there any way to restrict to direct supertypes tough ? Also, what is the utility of isInstanceOf then ?

Comment: Restricting to direct supertypes : no way to do that, not sure how useful that could be. Utility of isInstanceOf : it works if the parameter is an explicit type name, not a type parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
def cast[T >: Type](x: T, errMsg: String): T = { ... }
```

However, you might want to reconsider the necessity of explicit typecasts in Scala.

Comment: Actually I want it so both "T" and "Type" are unknown. (I shouldn't have used Type tough, I seem to recall it is a java class.)